# How to update a DataGridView's Datasource on cell edit

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've attached my class Reports to a dataGridView's DataSource through the Select statement below because I don't want Prop3 showing up in the DGV. I then updated the cellClick event to remove ReadOnly because that seemed to be an issue through initial runs.

When I click a cell and try to change a value to 123 it switches back to 456 once I hit enter. I've attempted to use various other events such as CellEndEdit, CellValueChanged, and any other event I thought may help to no luck. I cannot even find the value (123) I'm attempting to change to stored anywhere while running the code with breakpoints. I want to make sure that the value in myClass gets set to 123 after the cell edit has completed. If I don't use the select statement then all 3 properties will display in the DGV and I can then edit values the way I'm asking to do, but again I don't want Prop3 showing so used the select statement.

```
    List<MyClass> myClass;
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myClass = new List<MyClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            myClass.Add(new MyClass(456, 456));
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = myClass.Select(x => new { x.Prop1, x.Prop2 }).ToList();
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
        dataGridView1.CellClick += DataGridView1_CellClick;
    }

    private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell.ReadOnly = false;

    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Prop1{get;set;}
        public int Prop2 {get;set;}
        public int Prop3 {get;set;}
        public MyClass(int prop1, int prop2)
        {
            Prop1 = prop1;
            Prop2 = prop2;
        }
        public MyClass() { }
    }
```

Comment: Setting the WHOLE `DataGridView` to read only… `dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;` … will override the individual rows/cols/cells read only property. If you set the individual rows or columns as read only = true, then you can set a single cell to read only = false.

Comment: DataGridView was already set ReadOnly  = false; but even after adding that to the CellClick event I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: You state that… _”However once I finish editing a cell the value reverts back to what was stored before.”_ … ? Can you create an [mre] that demonstrates the check box getting set back to its original value? If the user changes the value of the check box in the grid, then the underlying DataSource is also changed automatically. So it is unclear what you mean by “How to update a DataGridView’s DataSource”.

Comment: What is the point of any of the code you have written? It seems to be nothing to do with the title of your question, which also seems to be a bad idea. Why set a grid to read only and then set a cell clicked on to editable? That's exactly how a grid behaves anyway; the editing control only shows for one cell at a time. A datagridview does reliably edit the values of the properties of the underlying DataSource - why are you trying to micromanage it? Are you simply looking for something like DataGridView.EndEdit, to flush an edit to the underlying list before eg you save (which usually happens..

Comment: ..on focus lost anyway)

Comment: I'm never setting the a grid to read only. I'm forcing it to not read-only because I thought that maybe causing an issue. The issue is in the select statement. If I don't use a select statement all three Properties (Prop1, Prop2, and Prop3) will display in the datagridview, which will then allow me to properly edit the values, but I only want Prop1 and Prop2 to show up. I then need to be able to edit Prop1 and Prop2 values by just being able to type into the DGV. Which should then update the Prop1 or Prop2 properties in the List of MyClass

Comment: Also I don't understand what's hard about the statement "update a datasource." I've attached myClass list to the DGV's datasource and when I edit the DGV in runtime. I want to make sure myClass updates as well. With the current code that doesn't happen

Comment: it doesn't matter anyways I'm just going to setup the Browsable attribute dynamically to do what I need

Comment: We are glad you found a solution. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

> because I don't want Prop3 showing up in the DGV

It's a lot simpler to just remove the column from the DGV after it's generated it

```
var x = new List<MyClass>(){
  new MyClass(){ Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = 22, Prop3 = 4015559191 },
  new MyClass(){ Prop1 = "Fred", Prop2 = 23, Prop3 = "4015559002" },
};
```

Appreciate that by default a DataGridView's `AutoGenerateColumns` property is true. When you bind to a list of MyClass, DGV will inspect the properties of MyClass and make columns for them, taking the datatype and name into account

Nothing stops you editing its creations afterwards:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = x;

dataGridView1.AutogenerateColumns = false; //turn it off so it doesn't later recreate removed columns
dataGridView1.Columns.Remove("Prop3"); //Prop3 property became a column named Prop3
```

> I want to make sure that the value in `myClass` gets set to 123 after the cell edit has completed.

But, the grid isn't bound to `myClass`; you created a new, different, totally separate List elsewhere in memory when you did `ToList()` in  `myClass.Select(...).ToList()` and bound the grid to the new list.

Worse, in the `Select` you made new anonymous typed object and copied the data contents of the properties of your MyClass items over, which fully disconnected the instances of `MyClass` stored in `myClass` and bound the grid to a list full of anonymous types that just happened to have copies of the data

> When I click a cell and try to change a value to 123 it switches back to 456 once I hit enter

The straw that breaks the camel's back is that *anonymous types are immutable* - you've bound your grid to a brand new list, full of brand new read only anonymous types..

..the grid could never influence the contents of `myClass`